# Can we create sandbox via metadata in apex salesforce?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata, sandbox, production

I know that it can be impossible ,
I have requirements to create a sandbox for organization via a button on Custom object record.
Can we create a sandbox via metadata in Apex or some process ?

Any help will be appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the REST API to insert a [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm), which will create a Sandbox to your specifications. This is fairly trivial to do:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(
  Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalFormat() +
  'services/data/v52.0/tooling/sobjects/SandboxInfo');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setBody(body); // This will be a JSON string
HttpResponse res = new http().send(req);
```

This is an asynchronous process; the return value gives you an ID you can use to monitor the progress of this request. Check the documentation for full details.

Comment: Thank you a lot.
It is exactly what I was looking for.